# Unable to host Storybook on subpath

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, storybook

I have a storybook for my react components, and when trying to host the static build of story book at root path (i.e: https://some-domain.com/), then the storybook works fine. However, when trying to host at a sub path such as https://some-domain.com/subpath I get error below from console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[ÂªÂµÂºÃ€-°-Í´Í¶Í·Íº-
Í½Í¿Î†Îˆ-ÎŠÎŒÎŽ-Î¡Î£-ÏµÏ·-ÒÒŠ-Ô¯Ô±-Õ–Õ™Õ -Öˆ×-×ª×¯-×²Ø -ÙŠÙ®Ù¯Ù±-Û“Û•Û¥Û¦Û®Û¯Ûº-Û¼Û¿ÜÜ’-Ü¯Ý-Þ¥Þ±ßŠ-ßªß
´-à¦€à¦…-à¦Œà¦à¦à¦“-à¦¨à¦ª-à¦°à¦²à¦¶-à¦¹à¦½à§Žà§œà§à§Ÿ-à¨à¨à¨“-à¨¨à¨ª-à¨°à¨²à¨³à¨µà¨¶à¨¸à¨¹à©™-
à©œà©žà©²-à©´àª…-àªàª-àª‘àª²à¬³à¬µ-à¬¹à¬½à­œà­à­Ÿ-à­¡à­±à®ƒà®…-à®Šà®Ž-à®à®’-à®•à®™à®šà®œà®žà®Ÿà®£à®¤à®¨-
à®ªà®®-à®¹à¯à°…-à°Œà°Ž-à°à°’-à°¨à°ª-à°¹à°½à±˜-à±šà± à±¡à²€à²…¸²à¸³à¹€-à¹†àºàº‚àº„àº†-àºŠàºŒ-àº£àº¥àº§-
àï­ï­ƒï­„ï­†-ï®±ï¯“-ï´½ïµ-ï¶ï¶’-ï·‡ï·°-ï·»ï¹°-ï¹´ï¹¶-ï»¼ï¼¡-ï¼ºï½-ï½šï½¦-ï¾¾ï¿‚-ï¿‡ï¿Š-ï¿ï¿’-ï¿—ï
¿š-ï¿œ]/: Range out of order in character class
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at Module.<anonymous> (vendors~main.ba0ee86f12448108b672.bundle.js:1)
    at Module.ia (ruxitagentjs_ICA2SVfgjqru_10201200909073022.js:308)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime~main.ba0ee86f12448108b672.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendors~main.ba0ee86f12448108b672.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.ia (ruxitagentjs_ICA2SVfgjqru_10201200909073022.js:308)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime~main.ba0ee86f12448108b672.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendors~main.ba0ee86f12448108b672.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.ia (ruxitagentjs_ICA2SVfgjqru_10201200909073022.js:308)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime~main.ba0ee86f12448108b672.bundle.js:1)
```

Base on what I understand, it seems like SB is trying to find some script at the root path instead of subpath, and since the static folder is served under the subpath, it won't be able to find what it's looking for in the root bath. Do correct me on this if I'm wrong. After some googling, I tried modifying the  tag in the iframe.html file to have src pointed to the subpath but that doesn't seem to help either. Can someone help me on this please?

Comment: Hello @Nathan, could you provide your SB configuration / Webpack configuration if any?

Comment: This is probably a bug in storybook. I suggest you open a github issue. Why? because it works on the main path and only fails for sub-path. Secondly the regex  could be faulty trying to find the (assuming relative files by the config file) using slash/back matching.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `publicPath` in `iframe-webpack-config.js` which should solve your issue.

I have found the solution [here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/1291). You can checkout that tread for more information.